# Anchors inside of [ ] in sed

Tags: regex, sed

Using sed, why does this match:

```
sed 's/test$/pass/' <<< "test"
```

...when this doesn't?

```
sed 's/test[$]/pass/' <<< "test"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `[…]` represents a character class in a regular expression, so `[$]` matches a single literal `$` character.

In other words, you cannot match anchors inside character classes. So if you want to do something like match an `a` or `b` character or the end of the string, use an alternation:

```
sed 's/test([ab]|$)/pass/' <<< "test"
```

Comment: On the same lines, you will notice other reserved characters will have different affects when in a character class (`[.]` vs `.`).

Answer (score 1):

`test[$]` means to match with `test$` string.

Whereas the regex `test$` means to match the `test` from a string which is at the end of it. For example:

```
test is a test
          +--+ is matched for test$
```

Comment: A better example would be: `test$ is a test`